# Coalesce rows based on multiple columns and join multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df like

```
Code  Country     CID      New_Country
123   Aus         C11      Europe
123   Aus         C12      India
456   Europe      C98      US
456   Europe      C123     US
456   Europe      C43      Europe
112   US          C345     China
```

I want resultant df like this:

```
Code  Country     Merged_Column             
123   Aus         C11,Europe;C12,India          
456   Europe      C98,US;C123,US;C43,Europe
112   US          C345,China
```

**Problem Statement**

I want to coalesce rows based on multiple columns (`Code` and `Country`) and want to merge two columns (`CID` and `New_Country`)

**My Code:**

```
df=df.groupby(['Code','Country'])['CID'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

The above code is working for one column, but need help on coalescing two columns as shown in resultant df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[`series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) for concating 2 cols and then [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)+`groupby()`

```
df.assign(Merged_Column=df['CID'].str.cat(df['Country'],sep=',')).groupby(
   ['Code','Country'],sort=False,as_index=False)['Merged_Column'].agg(';'.join)
```

Or:
[`df.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with `.join` on `axis=1` for multiple cols with same steps as above

```
df.assign(Merged_Column=df[['CID','New_Country']].agg(','.join,1)).groupby(
     ['Code','Country'],sort=False,as_index=False)['Merged_Column'].agg(';'.join)
```

---

```
   Code Country              Merged_Column
0   123     Aus       C11,Europe;C12,India
1   456  Europe  C98,US;C123,US;C43,Europe
2   112      US                 C345,China
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! Using the 2nd solution as I have multiple columns in groupby and multiple columns to join also!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal No problem, yes the second one helps for multiple col concatenation :)